# Date Time Format Issue

Tags: .net

How can I convert DD/MM/YYYY (time is not here) date format to dd-MM-yyyy format. 
Please make sure I have only DD/MM/YYYY it includes no time and I want to convert it to dd-MM-YYYY format.
Please help.

Comment: Question is vague, please clarify.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx (parse) + http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx (format)

Answer (score 3):

in **C# language** Code.

```
string from = "17/5/1983";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(from, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
string to = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Out Put : 17-05-1983**

String to returns your expected DateTime format..
I tried, It works fine.

Try this code 
It convert datetime format into the "DD-MM-YYYY" format

Here's the MSDN Documentation on the subject: Custom Date and Time Format Strings

Please Mark As a Answer.

- Thanks
  Abhishek

Comment: He has not `DateTime` object yet, obviously.

Comment: Time will not come in DD/MM/YYYY format. So, if I want to convert this using datetime method, its throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot abhishek.. I have one more question..Is there a way to validate the excel column against data type. Let's say I have an excel sheet containing Rate column, I want this column to be numeric using C#

Comment: I replied Answer for your question .. please check it.. please mark is as Answer..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) in .NET - example in C#:

```
DateTime inputTime = DateTime.ParseExact("11/01/2011", 
                                         "d/M/yyyy", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string outputTime = inputTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Time will not come in DD/MM/YYYY format. So, if I want to convert this using datetime method, its throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

**In C# language**  
The Below code to import excel into dataset.

```
/************************** Code **********************************/
String strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=C:\\Book2.xls;" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//You must use the $ after the object
//you reference in the spreadsheet
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter
("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", strConn);

//da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "ExcelTest");

da.Fill(ds);
DataTable _Dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in _Dt.Rows)
        {   int outint=0;
            if(Int32.TryParse(Convert.ToString(row[0]),out outint))
            {
                // write your code here
                // if condition is true then it validate the integer otherwise it is not valid number format
            }
        }

/************************************************************/
```

Try it.
Let you know if any problem.

Thanks
Abhishek